# How to convert .docx file to byte array (Python)

Tags: python, file, ms-word, byte, docx

Is there a way to convert the whole **.docx** file from Word to byte array **with Python** and then convert the byte array to a .docx file ?

Comment: You could open the file in binary mode and read it to a bytes object then write it again. `doc = open('file1.docx', 'rb').read();open('file2.docx', 'wb').write(doc)`. Do you need something else?

Comment: That's everything that i wanted. Simple and awesome, thanks !

Comment: You should be aware that modern office files are basically zip files where the .zip is replaced by the document type extension.